# Searching file python

Tags: python

Using this code
I want that it search all the files with name sh like sh.c,sh.txt,sh.cpp etc.But this code does not search unless I write **lookfor=sh.txt** or **lookfor=sh.pdf** instead of **lookfor=sh** in the below code.
Hence I want that by writing **lookfor=sh** it searches all files named sh.Please help.

```
import os
from os.path import join
lookfor = "sh"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    if lookfor in files:
          print "found: %s" % join(root, lookfor)
          break
```

Answer (score 3):

Try glob:

```
import glob
print glob.glob('sh.*') #this will give you all sh.* files in the current dir
```

Comment: or `glob.glob('/**/sh*')` to get them all

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
if lookfor in files:
```

With:

```
for filename in files:
    if filename.rsplit('.', 1)[0] == lookfor:
```

---

What `filename.rsplit('.', 1)[0]` is remove the rightmost part of the file that's found after a dot (== the extension). In case the file has several dots in it, we keep the rest in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if lookfor in files:
```

says that the following code should be executed if the list `files` contains the string given in `lookfor`.

However, you want that the test should be that the found file name *starts* with the given string and continues with a `.`.

Besides, you want the real filename to be determined.

So your code should be

```
import os
from os.path import join, splitext
lookfor = "sh"
found = None
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    for file in files: # test them one after the other
        if splitext(filename)[0] == lookfor:
            found = join(root, file)
            print "found: %s" % found
            break
    if found: break
```

This can even be improved, as I don't like the way how I break the outer `for` loop.

Maybe you want to have it as a function:

```
def look(lookfor, where):
    import os
    from os.path import join, splitext
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(where):
        for file in files: # test them one after the other
            if splitext(filename)[0] == lookfor:
                found = join(root, file)
                return found

found = look("sh", "C:\\")
if found is not None:
    print "found: %s" % found
```

Comment: This would report `my.file.pdf` when you look for `my`. Nevertheless, +1 for `found = join(root, file)`

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to search for files with *sh* as their *basename*. (The part of the name excluding the path and extension.) You can do this with the `filter` function from the `fnmatch` module.

```
import os
from os.path import join
import fnmatch
lookfor = "sh.*"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    for found in fnmatch.filter(files, lookfor):
        print "found: %s" % join(root, found)
```

Comment: The term "basename" does not exclude the extension. See `help(os.path.basename)`.

Comment: Thnx for the answer it is printing all files but the name is coming sh.* I want a proper name of a file like sh.txt instead of sh.*.

Comment: @glglgl Removing the extension is a lesser-known use of the standard UNIX `basename` utility, but it is just as valid and standard. [Reference here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/basename.html) Note that I didn't link to the *python* basename utility because I'm not talking about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from os.path import join
lookfor = "sh."
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    for filename in files: 
      if filename.startswith(lookfor):
           print "found: %s" % join(root, filename)
```

You may want to read the doc for fnmatch and glob too.